# Can I upload only template files on google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Looking for a suggestion.

I have uploaded an app on playstore. In that app, I have few **templates of questionnaire (xml files - stored in resources)**.

Client modifies some of the templates once in a month or two.
When client modifies the template, I need to sign and upload APK again.

Is there any way out to **upload only the template resources** and enable app to read them or something?

*Like for media players, **themes** are uploaded as different package or application, but once downloaded they are part of MediaPlayer.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, as you guessed, the only practical approach is to upload a new APK every time there is new content.

Two ways to solve this:

**1. The elegant solution:**

If you can re-architect your app to communicate with a web service, you can store your templates there. Once a user installs and runs your app, you can have the app contact the service, authenticate if needed, and download the templates. This can be done once on login or every time the app is run - purely a design decision.

The minimum functionality you need from a web service is an online database. One example is Parse, which is going to discontinue service soon. Another is Firebase, which is free and fairly easy to use. You could store your XML templates in Firebase and have your app download them as needed.

This approach gives the developer control of the template content.

**2. The super hacky way**

Designate some directory in External Storage (this is important) to store these template files in, and have your app periodically scan this directory for templates to use. When there is a new or updated template, the user downloads the template and then copies it to that specific directory.

Obviously, this plan is full of holes - anything can go wrong here: users not knowing how or where to copy what, misformatted files, etc. And your userbase can have wildly different collections of templates and if something goes wrong, you won't know which templates a particular user has.

So there's the easy and the hard way. Obviously, I recommend the latter, if only for stability and sanity reasons...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions shobhik!
I had thought both the ways, but both have many limitations.
1. Unfortunately I can not re-architect the app and add web services.
2. App will be distributed to 100s of people, so practically cannot ask everyone to store files.


I am in middle of a wayout, will share what I have done if that works well ;)..

Comment: Sure thing! Btw, I just realized, nothing's stopping you from running a webserver and redirecting client applications requesting a fixed URL to the "right" version of a hosted XML file... could solve your problem if the number of templates is fixed.